# .ldaprc, ldaprc, or environment variables not recognized by LDAP

Tags: ldap, redhat

I have a set of RedHat 7 servers and need to override or set LDAP variables in the .ldaprc file in the home directory. The variables are:
SASL_NOCANON off
SASL_SECOPTS minssf=0,maxssf=0

We have .ldaprc working fine on several other hosts, but this new set of hosts will not honor the settings in the .ldaprc file. I also tried file name ldaprc, and exporting them as environment variables. Is there some other configuration setting needed to get .ldaprc recognized by LDAP and working? I've checked everything I can think of. Thanks for your help.